# Use spinner selection value for firebase query

Tags: android, listview, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I have an Android application in KOTLIN where I want to filter and display documents from a cloud_firestore collection. I want to filter the documents based on what the user selects from a drop down spinner. The problem is I cannot access the value of the spinner selection outside the scope of onItemSelected function.
The application works as I want it to if I hardcode the value of the string "sector" so I know the problem here is accessing the value of this variable (sector) outside the onItemSelected method every time it changes.
Here is my **HomeActivity.kt**

```
class HomeActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    val db by lazy { FirebaseFirestore.getInstance() }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home)

        var sector = ""

        //implement sector number spinner to get current user location
        val sectors = arrayOf("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", 10)

        val sectorOption = findViewById<View>(R.id.sectorOption) as Spinner

        if(sectorOption != null){
            val sectorAdapter = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, sectors)
            sectorOption.adapter = sectorAdapter

            sectorOption.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{
                override fun onItemSelected(
                    parent: AdapterView<*>?,
                    view: View?,
                    position: Int,
                    id: Long
                ) {
                    if (parent != null) {
                        sector = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()
                    }
                }
                override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {

                }
            }
        }

        var userList = mutableListOf<User>()
        var dataAdapter: DataAdapter?= null

        db.collection("users").whereEqualTo("sector", sector)
            .get()
            .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                if(task.isSuccessful){
                    userList.clear()
                    for(document in task.result!!){
                        Log.d(ContentValues.TAG, "test" + document.id + "=>" + document.data)

                        userList.add(User(document.get("Name").toString(), document.get("sector").toString()))
                    }
                    dataAdapter = DataAdapter(ArrayList(userList), applicationContext)
                    listview.setAdapter(dataAdapter)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you say "I cannot access the value of the spinner selection outside the scope of onItemSelected"? What is the value of `sector` in this line `db.collection("users").whereEqualTo("sector", sector)`?

Comment: @Alex Mamo, it stays as en empty string(the way it was initialised). However if I change the initialisation to something like var sector = "10", it works the way I want it to. I'm new to Android Kotlin, so please suggest if you think something else is causing this issue.

Comment: Have you tried to move that query inside `onItemSelected` function?